# Datatables with Django can not fetch data from MySQL Database

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I am trying to fetch data by searching in the default search bar provides by the [datatables](https://datatables.net/) using Django. The default view shows up but when I search in the search box, It shows nothing. The view it shows like this:
[image]

My View is this:

```
def searchProductTable(request):
    xh = ProductLaptop.objects.all()
    context = {
        "xh": xh
    }
    return render(request, "searchTableView.html", context)
```

for the model below:

```
class ProductLaptop(models.Model):
    laptops_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    laptops_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    laptops_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    laptops_image = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.laptops_name
```

I know the model is not correct and at the same time I do not know how will I implement the model cause I do not have that much experience with Django.

The code of my .html file is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Search Table</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
  <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Seller</th>
                <th>Price</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for foo in xh %}
            <tr>


                <td>{{ foo.laptops_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ foo.brand_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ foo.laptops_price}}</td>
                {% endfor %}


            </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#example').dataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:800/searchtable/',
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "laptops_name"},
        { "data": "brand_name"},
        { "data": "laptops_price"},
    ]
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me out to solve this problem. I have been trying to implement sorting, searching and pagination with DataTable for the last two days.

Comment: Not an expert in datatable, but maybe you can look into this: https://pypi.org/project/django-datatable/

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to specify explicitly column definitions within your HTML. All you need is `<table id="example"></table>`.

Also, you have to pay attention, that since you set 'dataSrc' to empty string, your client expects array of entries from the server.

So, you might want to check out possible errors and data format received from the server, using your browser's developer tools console, to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

for loop should be above `tbody`

Change your code to look like this:

```
{% for foo in xh %}
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ foo.laptops_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ foo.brand_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ foo.laptops_price}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```